# Codeigniter automatically encrypts my sessions in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

On my local server when i store session, data stored like this :

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1440489684;admin_login|s:1:"1";login_user_id|s:1:"1";name|s:9:"Mr. admin";login_type|s:5:"admin";
```

On my server it becames like this :

```
 58nyvA9O3PXABoqyVj8j8Y52TIRZCwUOYtNp3TjL4eVCsuYbvMQDbftpa9w7ahgy9M6XXR0-o6tWcKjW6Krlw2fUkoCYAESIQw4XFY89m-guUhqNyqgHg5XLjBVZeFr_QkjF1KhAaY3EGluJUSurxZRZPlNMBLW2Hv-0fMfTmIf3LhgPdeUTEHVgc_CpjHprpDbTu-aFNVA7piPMNjTxBJk0Nza3_Cl_IRUaFuO48QX67-DvMLOzcAGVoHjIQbAaDOJsECaalbGpKZbPQJE7vmNv8l15dbBP2ozn3H0Wwtw.
```

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: post the code that inserts it?

Comment: Is the server using Suhosin?

Comment: yes, server using it

Comment: Then that's probably the reason. Suhosin's config option `suhosin.session.encrypt` is by default set to On.

Comment: Can i disable it with ini_set or i need to change from php.ini?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the settings are able to be modified at run time, so yeah, probably in the php.ini, or depending on your setup, there may well be a specific suhosin.ini you can modiy / update. It really depends on your setup. Though is it necessary to disable it?

Comment: Yes, it must be disabled, I'm in position to not able to change my codes. Thanks for help if you type your comment as answer i ll choose it.